# How to setup cloudwatch metrics for dynamically created resources in auto-scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

We have some auto-scaling groups and would like to add metrics for members of that to our cloudwatch dashboard / alarming.

In particular, we would like to know the metrics of the EBS (e.g. BurstBalance) attached to the instances of a certain auto-scaling group. These metrics should of course be updated when a new instance is spawned or a instance is being terminated by the ASG. So we want to see the updated metrics on the corresponding cloudwatch dashboard widgets.

Ideally, we would gather those metrics from the volumes by the assigned tags.

Has anyone an idea how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We have developed a SaaS Marketplace product for those issues. We use Instance Name Tag to build CloudWatch dashboards, and if you trigger the endpoint after infrastructure changes (e.g. as part of your infrastructure) you will get up-to-date dashboard. All available metrics for EBS volumes are presented in the same dashboard as the EC2 instances and tagged with the name of the instance, instead of the cryptic vol-asd143

Currently, the endpoint filters instances only, but the AutoscalingGroup will be released in upcoming weeks and you can start using the endpoint if your instances have the Name tag set.

Product Page: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B079VCQ2T8

Blog with details: https://blog.envimate.com/easy-aws-monitoring-using-cloudwatch-envimation/

Blog post of why we needed this: https://blog.envimate.com/aws-native-monitoring-using-cloudwatch-dashboards/

Hope this helps and I'll happily hear feedback on your experience with the product.

Comment: Thank you for this, we will have a look at it.